# Allow the user to start multiple processes with redirected output and input for all of them

Tags: c#, redirect, input, process, output

**I've been working on a project called Borealis Server Manager (https://github.com/cyberstrawberry101/Borealis-Server-Manager) since May of this year.  I need help from anyone skilled enough in C# to do the following:**

- Allow the user to start multiple gameserver processes with arguments given to them, in upwards of dozens or hundreds of them as background processes, and still be able to switch the redirected output and input to those processes on-the-fly to the console window within Borealis.

This is what the console page looks like in Borealis:
[You can see the screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX3hk.png)

This is the code that currently launches the programs, merged with some code that was suggested by another Facepunch user months ago, but their new code seems to freeze Borealis while even one server is running, which is actually a step backwards, and I can't even get it to properly redirect console output into my console window in Borealis.  I am completely okay with a rewrite of the code should someone step up to help Borealis enter beta stages.  I've had the code functional enough to launch the servers externally, but internally, I can only get one server's output at a time, without killing all of the other servers.  It's a pretty complex problem.

```
using MetroFramework;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Borealis
{
    public partial class TAB_CONTROL : Form
    {
        #region pInvoke
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern bool FreeConsole();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlDelegate HandlerRoutine, bool Add);

        // Delegate type to be used as the Handler Routine for SCCH
        delegate Boolean ConsoleCtrlDelegate(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

        // Enumerated type for the control messages sent to the handler routine
        enum CtrlTypes : uint
        {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CtrlTypes dwCtrlEvent, uint dwProcessGroupId);

        public static void StopProgramByAttachingToItsConsoleAndIssuingCtrlCEvent(Process proc)
        {
            //This does not require the console window to be visible.
            if (AttachConsole((uint)proc.Id))
            {
                //Disable Ctrl-C handling for our program
                SetConsoleCtrlHandler(null, true);
                GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CtrlTypes.CTRL_C_EVENT, 0);

                //Must wait here. If we don't and re-enable Ctrl-C handling below too fast, we might terminate ourselves.
                var wasAborted = false;
                var procTask = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    //This is necessary because when we kill the process, it obviously exits. At that point, there is no proc object to wait for any longer
                    if (!wasAborted)
                        proc.WaitForExit();
                });
                if (!procTask.Wait(10000))
                {
                    wasAborted = true;
                    proc.Kill();
                }

                FreeConsole();

                //Re-enable Ctrl-C handling or any subsequently started programs will inherit the disabled state.
                SetConsoleCtrlHandler(null, false);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private CancellationTokenSource cancelToken;
        public TAB_CONTROL()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //===================================================================================//
        // UI HANDLING CODE                                                                  //
        //===================================================================================//
        private void ServerControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Pull all gameserver data from gameservers.json, split all json strings into a list, iterate through that list for specific data.
            if (GameServer_Management.server_collection != null)
            {
                foreach (GameServer_Object gameserver in GameServer_Management.server_collection)
                {
                    comboboxGameserverList.Items.Add(gameserver.SERVER_name_friendly);
                }
            }
        }
        private void comboboxGameserverList_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GameServer_Object gameserver in GameServer_Management.server_collection)
            {
                if (gameserver.SERVER_name_friendly == comboboxGameserverList.Text)
                {
                    //Decide what data to pull from the object at this point in time of development.

                    GameServer_Object Controlled_GameServer = new GameServer_Object();

                    Controlled_GameServer.DIR_install_location = Controlled_GameServer.DIR_install_location;
                    Controlled_GameServer.SERVER_executable = Controlled_GameServer.SERVER_executable;
                    Controlled_GameServer.SERVER_launch_arguments = Controlled_GameServer.SERVER_launch_arguments;
                    Controlled_GameServer.SERVER_running_status = Controlled_GameServer.SERVER_running_status;

                }
            }
            btnStartServer.Visible = true;
            chkAutoRestart.Visible = true;
            lblAutoRestart.Visible = true;
            chkStandaloneMode.Visible = true;
            lblStandaloneMode.Visible = true;
            consolePanel.Visible = true;
        }
        private void proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                consoleOutputList.Items.Add(e.Data);
            }
        }
        private void RefreshData()
        {
            comboboxGameserverList.Items.Clear();
            if (GameServer_Management.server_collection != null)
            {
                foreach (GameServer_Object gameserver in GameServer_Management.server_collection)
                {
                    comboboxGameserverList.Items.Add(gameserver.SERVER_name_friendly);
                }
            }
        }
        private void ServerControl_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshData();
        }
        private void chkStandaloneMode_OnValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkStandaloneMode.Value == true)
            {
                consolePanel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                consolePanel.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        //===================================================================================//
        // SERVER CONTROL:                                                                   //
        //===================================================================================//
        private void LaunchServer(string SERVER_executable, string SERVER_launch_arguments, Action<string> redirectedOutputCallback = null, TextReader input = null, string argWorkingDirectory = null, EventHandler onExitedCallback = null, CancellationToken cancelToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.Arguments = SERVER_launch_arguments;
            startInfo.FileName = SERVER_executable;

            if (redirectedOutputCallback != null)  //Redirect Output to somewhere else.
            {
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //Redirect the programs.
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

                try
                {
                    // Start the process with the info we specified.
                    // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.

                    using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo))
                    {
                        if (onExitedCallback != null)
                        {
                            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                            process.Exited += onExitedCallback;
                        }

                        if (cancelToken != null)
                        {
                            cancelToken.Register(() =>
                            {
                                StopProgramByAttachingToItsConsoleAndIssuingCtrlCEvent(process);
                                redirectedOutputCallback?.Invoke("Shutting down the server...");
                            });
                        }

                        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args?.Data))
                                redirectedOutputCallback(args.Data);
                        };
                        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

                        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args?.Data))
                                redirectedOutputCallback(args.Data);
                        };
                        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                        //For whenever input is needed
                        string line;
                        while (input != null && (line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
                            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(line);
                        process.WaitForExit();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    StringBuilder errorDialog = new StringBuilder();
                    errorDialog.Append("There was an error launching the following server:\n")
                               .Append(startInfo.FileName)
                               .Append("\n\n")
                               .Append("[Retry]: Attempt to start the same server again.\n")
                               .Append("[Cancel]: Cancel attempting to start server.");
                }
            }
            else  //No not redirect output somewhere else
            {
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = true; //Execute the programs.

                try
                {
                    // Start the process with the info we specified.
                    // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
                    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                    {
                        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    StringBuilder errorDialog = new StringBuilder();
                    errorDialog.Append("There was an error launching the following server:\n")
                               .Append(startInfo.FileName)
                               .Append("\n\n")
                               .Append("[Retry]: Attempt to start the same server again.\n")
                               .Append("[Cancel]: Cancel attempting to start server.");
                }
            }
        }
        private void btnStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GameServer_Management.server_collection != null)
            {
                foreach (GameServer_Object gameserver in GameServer_Management.server_collection)
                {
                    if (gameserver.SERVER_name_friendly == comboboxGameserverList.Text)
                    {
                        //SOURCE ENGINE HANDLER
                        if (gameserver.ENGINE_type == "SOURCE")
                        {
                            //Check to see if the gameserver needs to be run with a visible console, or directly controlled by Borealis.
                            if (chkStandaloneMode.Value == true) //To be hopefully depreciated soon.  Only needed right now as a fallback option to server operators.
                            {
                                LaunchServer(gameserver.DIR_install_location + @"\steamapps\common" + gameserver.DIR_root + gameserver.SERVER_executable,
                                    string.Format("{0} +port {1} +map {2} +maxplayers {3}",
                                    gameserver.SERVER_launch_arguments,
                                    gameserver.SERVER_port,
                                    gameserver.GAME_map,
                                    gameserver.GAME_maxplayers));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                LaunchServer(gameserver.DIR_install_location + @"\steamapps\common" + gameserver.DIR_root + gameserver.SERVER_executable,
                                string.Format("{0} +port {1} +map {2} +maxplayers {3}",
                                gameserver.SERVER_launch_arguments,
                                gameserver.SERVER_port,
                                gameserver.GAME_map,
                                gameserver.GAME_maxplayers));
                            }
                        }

                        //SOURCE ENGINE HANDLER
                        if (gameserver.ENGINE_type == "UNREAL")
                        {
                            //Check to see if the gameserver needs to be run with a visible console, or directly controlled by Borealis.
                            if (chkStandaloneMode.Value == true)
                            {
                                /*LaunchServer(gameserver.DIR_install_location + @"\steamapps\common" + gameserver.DIR_root + gameserver.SERVER_executable, 
                                    string.Format("{0}?{1}?Port={2}?MaxPlayers={3}",
                                    gameserver.GAME_map,
                                    gameserver.SERVER_launch_arguments,
                                    gameserver.SERVER_port,
                                    gameserver.GAME_maxplayers));
                                */
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MetroMessageBox.Show(BorealisServerManager.ActiveForm, "Unfortunately Borealis cannot directly control console output at this time; instead, please launch the server in 'standalone mode'.", "Unable to launch server within Borealis.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                /*
                                chkAutoRestart.Visible = false;
                                lblAutoRestart.Visible = false;
                                chkStandaloneMode.Visible = false;
                                lblStandaloneMode.Visible = false;
                                btnStartServer.Enabled = false;
                                btnStopServer.Visible = true;
                                consolePanel.Visible = true;
                                txtboxIssueCommand.Visible = true;
                                txtboxIssueCommand.Text = " > Enter a Command";
                                txtboxIssueCommand.Enabled = true;
                                Execute(Environment.CurrentDirectory + gameserver.SERVER_executable, gameserver.SERVER_launch_arguments, true);
                                */
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void btnStopServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStopServer.Visible = false;
            btnStartServer.Enabled = true;
            chkAutoRestart.Visible = true;
            lblAutoRestart.Visible = true;
            txtboxIssueCommand.Visible = false;
            consoleOutputList.Items.Clear();
            txtboxIssueCommand.Text = " > Server is Not Running";
            txtboxIssueCommand.Enabled = false;

            cancelToken.Cancel();
            backgroundWorker01.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender2, e2) =>
            {
                btnStopServer.Enabled = false;
                btnStartServer.Enabled = true;
                txtboxIssueCommand.Enabled = false;
                txtboxIssueCommand.Text = "> Server is not running";
                consoleOutputList.Items.Add("Server stopped...");
            };
        }
        private void txtboxIssueCommand_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtboxIssueCommand.Text = "";
        }
        private void txtboxIssueCommand_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            txtboxIssueCommand.Text = "";
        }
        private void backgroundWorker01_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            bool stopped = false;


            //It's an assumption that these 3 elements MUST exist
            var asyncCallback = comboboxGameserverList.BeginInvoke((Func<string[]>)delegate ()
            {
                return new string[] {
                    //GameServerXMLData( comboboxGameserverList.SelectedItem as string, "installation_folder" ),
                    //GameServerXMLData( comboboxGameserverList.SelectedItem as string, "default_launchscript" ),
                    //GameServerXMLData( comboboxGameserverList.SelectedItem as string, "binaries" )
                };
            });
            asyncCallback.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            var serverParams = comboboxGameserverList.EndInvoke(asyncCallback) as string[];

            Action<string> textAddCallback = (args) =>
            {
                consoleOutputList.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
                {
                    consoleOutputList.Items.Add(args);
                });
            };

            EventHandler exitedHandler = (sender2, e2) =>
            {
                if (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    //Wait a little until we restart the server
                    consoleOutputList.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
                    {
                        consoleOutputList.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                        consoleOutputList.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                        consoleOutputList.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);

                        consoleOutputList.Items.Add("An error occured and the process has crashed. Auto-restarting in 5 seconds...");
                        //Scroll to the bottom
                        consoleOutputList.TopIndex = consoleOutputList.Items.Count - 1;

                        consoleOutputList.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                        consoleOutputList.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                        consoleOutputList.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                    });
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                else
                    stopped = true;
            };

            while (chkAutoRestart.Value && !stopped)
                LaunchServer(serverParams[0] + serverParams[2], serverParams[1], textAddCallback, null, serverParams[0], chkAutoRestart.Value ? exitedHandler : null, chkAutoRestart.Value ? cancelToken.Token : default(System.Threading.CancellationToken));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)